# How to generate PHP getters and setters in NetBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8

I saw in NetBeans 8 refactoring functionality for automatic creation of getters and setters from class properties. It was working on Java code, but it seems that for PHP code it isn't working. Is it possible to enable this functionality or get some extension, which does that?

Answer (score 15):

> Just right click in side the class body,not over the class variables
>   and choose insert code option as shown in third image.
>   link:http://w.planetnetbeans.org/topic28565.html

[image: getters and setters]

[image: generate option]
[image: insert code option]

Answer (score 3):

first, the caret position has to be inside a PHP class and you have to press shortcut ALT+Insert (CTLRL+I on Mac). After invoking the shortcut, all possible generators are offered.

Answer (score 2):

Place your cursor in the class, on the empty line and then hit ALT+Insert. You getter and setter options